# Problems with production using Kubernete of Google Cloud Platform, and GitLab CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab CI/CD to automatically transfer the code after every push to the master branch. Everything is going well there. But when Kubernete gets the code, it throws this error message:

[image: screenshot #1]

Extended error:

[image: screenshot #2]

I need some help about that.

Comment: You're going to have to include the container logs, as **no one** can troubleshoot from a screenshot saying "it crashed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CrashLoopBackoff error means that GKE is trying to launch a Pod but the containers within are crashing or being terminated.

There is no simple answer to this. This is a specific error within your application which could be caused by various reasons. You will have to investigate it by looking [through the logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting).

By the way, I found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537834/debugging-a-container-in-a-crash-loop-on-kubernetes) that looks very similar to yours.